# Using the content of a register in a ex command

Tags: vim

Buffer 0 contains the name of a file that I want to insert in the current vim buffer. 
What I try doesn't work:

```
:r @0
```

In general, how can one use the content of a register in an ex script?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways:

- When typing the command interactively, the `<C-R>` command inserts a register (or Vimscript expression via the `=` register): `:r <C-r>0` There are many useful variants, see `:help c_CTRL-R`. You can also use this in a mapping, though I would prefer the alternative:
- Interpolating the register contents via `:execute`, i.e. you're building the command as a string first: `:execute 'read ' . @0`